# Is there a way to automatically printf a float to the number of decimal places it has?

Tags: c, floating-point

I've written a program to display floats to the appropriate number of decimal places:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%.2f, %.10f, %.5f, %.5f\n", 1.27, 345.1415926535, 1.22013, 0.00008);
}
```

Is there any kind of conversion character that is like `%.(however many decimal places the number has)f` or do they always have to be set manually?

Comment: There's nothing inherent in a floating point value to determine how many decimals it has. You'll have to manage that at runtime or hard code it in.

Comment: Maybe what you want is to drop trailing zeros from the output?   `%g` will do this.

Comment: FP values don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and the two are incommensurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically printf a float to the number of decimal places it has?

Use `"%g"`.  `"%g"` lops off trailing zero digits.

> ... unless the # flag is used, any trailing zeros are removed from the fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character is removed if there is no fractional portion remaining.  C17dr § 7.21.6.1 8.

All finite floating point values are exactly representable in decimal - some need many digits to print exactly.  Up to `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` from `<float.h>` (typically 17) significant digits is sufficient - rarely a need for more.

Pass in a precision to encourage enough output, but not too much.

Remember values like `0.00008` are not exactly encoded in the typical binary floating point `double`, but a nearby value is used like `8.00000000000000065442...e-05`

```
printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, some_double);

printf("%.17g, %.17g, %.17g, %.17g\n", 1.27, 345.1415926535, 1.22013, 0.00008);
// 1.27, 345.14159265350003, 1.2201299999999999, 8.0000000000000007e-05
```

`DBL_DIG` (e.g. 15) may better meet OP's goal.

```
printf("%.15g, %.15g, %.15g, %.15g\n", 1.27, 345.1415926535, 1.22013, 0.00008);
// 1.27, 345.1415926535, 1.22013, 8e-05
```

---

Function to print a `double` - [exactly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) may take 100s of digits.

Comment: The number of significant decimal digits you need is exactly equal to the number of significant bits you have in the significand of the floating point format, which for an [IEEE double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is 53 bits.  However you have to add the number of leading zeroes after the decimal point.

Comment: @MarkRansom "number of significant decimal digits you need is exactly equal to the number of significant bits you have in the significand of the floating point format, which for an IEEE double is 53 bits" --> Disagree that one needs 53 decimal digits. More like 53*log(2) + a few significant digits are enough.   The number of decimal digits needed to _exactly_ represent a fraction like `DBL_MIN` is a function of the exponent more so than the significand. Suggest posting an answer that details your idea.

Comment: The exponent is exactly why I added the disclaimer that you need to add the leading zeros.

Comment: @MarkRansom i did not understand your comment. If it's for printing exactly, 2^-n is 5^n/10^n. 5^n can span many digits (the smallest bit for doube precision is 2^-1074, 5^1074 requires many decimal digits, not accounting for leading zeroes). If significant means enough digits to make floating point undistinguishable, then 53 is too much.

Comment: @aka.nice sorry for being unclear.  My comment was for printing the exact value, where the digits to the right of the last printed digit are all zero.  Fewer digits are required for distinguishable numbers although it's a surprisingly difficult problem, well studied by those that need to create standard printing libraries.  Take for example 2 bits to the right of the decimal point.  Two decimal digits are needed for exact representations: .0, .25, .5, or .75.  But only 1 digit is needed for unambiguous representations.

Comment: @MarkRansom "Two decimal digits are needed for exact representations: .0, .25, .5, or .75. But only 1 digit is needed for unambiguous representations" --> still unclear what is meant by  "number of significant _decimal_ digits you need is  53".  To exactly represent values like `DBL_MIN` need far more. To represent `DBL_MIN` enough to distinguish other `double` is about 17 significant decimal digits.  It is the claimed 53 that is suspicious.

Comment: Because 2 is a prime factor of 10, I thought that each base-10 digit would cover a base-2 digit.  I've tested that assumption many times over the years, and it's always held - until today.  I found that 0.05 requires 55 digits, and the problem keeps getting bigger as the numbers get smaller.  I will have to re-examine the math that led to my erroneous conclusion.  In the meantime please ignore everything I said above.

Comment: @MarkRansom You may find the link in my answer useful.  We can take down the comments if you like.

Answer (score -1):

`sprintf()` could help you
**There is no direct way to do this in my experience**
here is a simple algorithm to help you with this function

```
munber = float/double input
n = number of decimal places in float/double
char format[999];
sprintf(format ,"%%.%df" ,n);
printf(format, number);
```

`sprintf` is like `printf` but instead of writing to `stdout`, `sprintf` writes to a string.

Now you are left with finding number of digits after the precision.

Comment: Hi Mukul, thanks for your answer, I am quite new to programming, and I find it difficult to understand your answer. Can you explain what the different parts of your code are doing? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Building format strings is a hot mess, it makes it hard for static analysis to catch bugs and there is absoluately no need for it here,  `printf("%.*f", n, number);` will do the same thing

Comment: @M.M How does that work can you elaborate?

Comment: `char format[99];` with `"%%.%df"` is insufficient to print all `double`.  `sprintf(format ,"%%.%df" , DBL_MAX);` leads to UB like buffer overflow..